# Unwanted extra right padding while using bootstrap 4.5 card

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use [this](https://www.codeply.com/p/Ej8XdqIR25) exact bootstrap 4.5 card container in my react app but for some reason having below two issues:

1. All three cards in the deck are getting an extra right padding of 44px.
2. The card header does not have full border.

I do not have any extra styles or containers:

[image: ss1]

[image]

Here is my react component which I am rendering through react router:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Pricing(props) {
    return (
        <div className="container py-2">
            <div className="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
                <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm d-flex">
                    <div className="card-header">
                        <h4 className="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h1 className="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small className="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                        <li>10 users included</li>
                        <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                        <li>Email support</li>
                        <li>Help center access</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <h4 className="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h1 className="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small className="text-muted">/ mo</small>
                    </h1>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                        <li>20 users included</li>
                        <li>10 GB of storage</li>
                        <li>Priority email support</li>
                        <li>Help center access</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <h4 className="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h1 className="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small className="text-muted">/ mo</small>
                    </h1>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                        <li>30 users included</li>
                        <li>15 GB of storage</li>
                        <li>Phone and email support</li>
                        <li>Help center access</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

EDIT:
Removed the Pricing.css import, still the issue persists.

Comment: perhaps your style sheet is messing with the layout. share Pricing.css or other relevant code

Comment: Looks ok to me: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-dijkstra-ejt71?file=/src/App.js Might be someone edited the node module. I'd reinstall bootstrap

Comment: I am fetching bootstrap through CDN. Still removed node_modules, package-lock and reinstalled and restarted the node server. Still having this issue not sure whats going wrong. There is no parent CSS anywhere. I am just rendering this component through react router at a route '/pricing'.

Comment: well if that does not help, i guess you could override the padding within your custom css

Answer (score 0):

I did not do a comparison to yours but if I get that same snippet from here https://www.codeply.com/p/Ej8XdqIR25 it works.

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="container py-2">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm d">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>20 users included</li>
          <li>10 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Priority email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>30 users included</li>
          <li>15 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Phone and email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```